# Using memoization for storing values in ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, memoization

For a short array the following function works well.  It's supposed to return the first array pair that whe sum is equal to a given integer.  However, if the array has a length upwards of 10 million elements, the request times out, because (I think) is storing thousands of values in the variable I create in the first line.  I know I have to use memoization (||=) but have no idea how to use it.

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
number = 3
array2 = [1,2,3.....n] # millions of elements
combos = array1.combination(2).to_a
(combos.select { |x,y| x + y == number }).sort.first
```

I need to gather all possible pairs to sort them, I'm using select to go through the entire list and not stop at the first pair that returns true.

Comment: What is `INTEGER`? What is `ARRAY`? What do you do there? Why not `find` instead of `select` + `first`?

Comment: I modified the code.  I'm not using detect or find because they stop iterating once they find the first true.

Comment: but you want to find the first occurance anyway. What's the point in finding all, if only needed first?

Comment: Because I actually need the pair that begins with the lowest value.

Comment: converting a enumerator to an array is resourceful, there is no need to do that. Besides, it is not clear what you're asking

Comment: The `.to_a` is killing you here, that forces expansion. Why not `.lazy` instead chained through to a `first` with the block?

Comment: If you "know you have to use memoization", but don't know how to use it... which implies you don't know what it does; how do you know you have to use it?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the possible solutions.

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s)
  seen = {}
  for i in ints do
    return [s-i, i] if seen[s-i]
    seen[i] = true
  end
  nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_smallest(arr, nbr) 
  first, *rest = arr.sort
  until rest.empty?
    matching = rest.bsearch { |n| n == nbr - first }
    return [first, matching] unless matching.nil?
    first, *rest = rest
  end
  nil
end

arr = [12, 7, 4, 5, 14, 9]

find_smallest(arr, 19) #=> [5, 14]
find_smallest(arr, 20) #=> nil
```

I've used the method [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) (rather than [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to speed up the search for an element equal to `nbr - first` (O(log `rest.size`) vs. O(`rest.size`)).